# Run two or more Java EE projects from Eclipse at once on same server?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, server

I am building a web apps using MAVEN and SAP-HANA cloud.I am having problem with running multiple projects simultaneous.

Currently i am running web project(ESCMP-moblie) on server(Web JAVA). Now i would like to run another application or project(ESCMP-web) on same server but it gives error message as **server port:8080 in use -HTTP port** and terminates .

I ran project  by selecting `project(ESCMP-web) ->RUN AS -> RUN ON SERVER ->choose an existing server ->Web JAVA -> finish .`

How to run two projects on same server ?

Edit:

I would like to use same port and same JVM.
Server: neo-java-web-sdk-1.58.18.1 downloaded from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud 
Eclipse: JAVA EE IDE LUNA-4.4. 
Sysetm: Windows-8.1 pro 64 bit 
JDK : JDk-1.7.71

Comment: just put projects wars to server and just start is not ok?

Comment: What server are you trying to use? Do you want one or two JVM? You're talking about Eclipse here but it's not related to your problem... The error you got is because you try to launch 2 apps on the same port. If you launch the second app using a different port it will work but you'll have 2 jvms running.

Comment: Enterprise servers allow many applications to run at the same time.

Comment: @YeWin it gives message as i mentioned in the details .

Comment: If you are using something like tomcat, simply deploy each of the projects either using eclipse or manually. (details spared) and start the server or restart if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same Server-Runtime instance to deploy both projects, go to server tab and right click on the instance, click add/remove from there you can add projects to be deployed on the same instance, i did that before, just forget the exact steps, but it's doable.

you need to find this panel:
[image]

now all you have to do is to start the server from server tab. and deployed projects will be accessable from the same URL just use project context-path to access.

ex,

```
http://MACHINE_IP:8080/project1/index.jsp
http://MACHINE_IP:8080/project2/index.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a Tomcat (maybe customized by SAP) so it's not really an application server but it is a servlet container.

In tomcat to run multiple project on the same instance you just have to set your projects in the `work` directory. You can do it manually or you can do it through Eclipse if you want.

[Here is an old tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/) but I guess it still valid.